# how to to connect and use JDBCUtil

Tags: java

hi
i want to use Class `JDBCUtil` in java language and eclips workspace and I have the below code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class JDBCUtil {

static final String CONN_STR = "jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/";

static {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        System.err.println("Unable to load HSQL JDBC driver");
    }
}

public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    return DriverManager.getConnection(CONN_STR);
}
```

}

but when I run it, I get the below `Exception`:

```
Unable to load HSQL JDBC driver
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at domain.EnrollCtrl.getCurrentOfferings(EnrollCtrl.java:78)
    at ui.UI.main(UI.java:28)
```

in addition there is UI and EnrollCtrl and another file in this project but the error is in this path. 
how can i fix this error? should I do sth for connectin to  `jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/`?
thank U

Answer (score 1):

your `String CONN_STR = "jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/";` should be

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/xdb", "sa", "");
```

In some circumstances, you may have to use the following line to get the driver.

`Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver").newInstance();`

Comment: This won't actually help.. calling .newInstance() on the jdbcDriver class isn't going to help. Using DriverManager.getConnection() is the recommended route once the driver has registered it's self in it's static initializer

Answer (score 0):

The chances are that you are missing the `hsqldb.jar` file from your classpath or some other environmental issue.

It is difficult to be certain as your question is incredibly specific to your code and environment.

Comment: dear Gareth Can you explain more about hsqldb.jar and how to use it? I didn't use it in my class path and I don't know how do it

Comment: I'm guessing that since your jdbc url and driver names are HSQL ones then you are attempting to connect to a HSQL database. More information http://hsqldb.org/ if this isn't what you are trying need your going to read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and have another look at your question